# Nuget changes existing shared package reference to last package referenced

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, package-management

We are using an internal nuget server to handle a handful of common class libraries, and we manage our nuget packages at the solution level.

When a project (say MyProject) references a common library, say Newtonsoft.Json, the reference proprerly comes from **C:\dev\myproject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net461\Newtonsoft.Json.dll**.  The moment I add another package (say CommonProject) to MyProject that also references Newtonsoft.Json, the reference in MyProject **CHANGES** to **C:\dev\myproject\packages\CommonProject\lib\net461\Newtonsoft.Json.dll**.

This causes serious problems and a great deal of dll hell.  The moment one of these common projects changes one of their references - let's say CommonProject no longer uses Newtonsoft.Json.  The moment MyProject upgrades to the latest version of CommonProject, MyProject will now fail to compile because it can no longer find Newtonsoft.Json in **C:\dev\myproject\packages\CommonProject\lib\net461\Newtonsoft.Json.dll**.  MyProject still lists Newtonsoft.Json as a nuget package reference, and the Newtonsoft dll is still sitting pretty in the Newtonsoft.Json folder of packages, but the dll reference is jacked up from when I first added the CommonProject nuget package.  Nuget stupidly **CHANGED** every single shared package reference to map directly to the CommonProject folder instead of the packages folders for each of those packages.  Even if the projects are referencing the exact same version of the same package, nuget still changes the reference.

Moving all shared package references to the folder of the last package added is making me think that nuget isn't managing packages at all.

Please tell me I'm doing something wrong, and let me know how I can get the packages to be properly referenced from their respective folders.

Comment: Which project style are you using?
Which NuGet version?
Which NuGet client?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by project style.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and I think I have the latest nuget.  Are you saying you don't see the above behavior with a particular version?  I'm pretty sure they all act like I've described.

Comment: That would just help diagnosing what the actual issue is.

You can check what you NuGet version is in the Extensions and Updates dialog and selecting the extension. Or opening the package manager console and see what it prints out. 

The project style is how you declare your dependencies.
Do you have packages.config file in your project?
project.json?

Comment: Nuget is 3.5.0.1484.  We are using a shared packages folder just outside of all our project folders via a nuget.config file that specifies the path.